Liu lemma 3.3.17: Proper + affine = finite
This has been asked and answered before here. I'm not satisfied with the answer (probably I don't understand it). Also I don't want a proof of "proper+affine=finite" (which is here) but of the specific lemma of Liu.
The setup
We are given $\operatorname{Spec}B\to \operatorname{Spec}A$ proper. It is of finite type and suppose that $B\simeq A[T]/I$ so that $\operatorname{Spec}B$ is a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{A}_A^1$. Then we identify $\mathbb{A}_A^1$ with the open subscheme $D_+(T_2)$ inside $\operatorname{Proj}A[T_1,T_2]$ setting $T=T_1/T_2.$ So in the end we have the following compositions:
$$
\operatorname{Spec}B\to \mathbb{A}_A^1\to \mathbb{P}_A^1\to \operatorname{Spec}A \qquad{\color{red}*}
$$
Now Liu uses that this is proper combined with the fact that $\mathbb{P}_A^1\to\operatorname{Spec}A$ is separated to get that $\operatorname{Spec}B\to \mathbb{A}_A^1\to \mathbb{P}_A^1$ is proper.
My question
Why is the map in ${\color{red}*}$ proper? My quess would be that it coincides with the original morphism $\operatorname{Spec}B\to\operatorname{Spec}A$, but why? Is there a unique homomorphism $A\to A\to A[T]$? What am I missing?

Formatting Spec via $\operatorname{Spec}$ produces better spacing. I've made the upgrade for you this time, please keep this in mind for the future.

The composition $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \Bbb A^1_A \to \Bbb P^1_A \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ of the defined maps is simply the original morphism $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$.
Let $f:A\to B$ be the ring map corresponding to the original morphism $\operatorname{Spec} B\to \operatorname{Spec} A$. The assumption that $B$ is singly generated over $A$ means that there is an element $b\in B$ such that the map $g:A[T]\to B$ defined by $g(a)= f(a)$, $g(T)= b$ is surjective, and so we may write $f$ as $A\to A[T]\to B\cong A[T]/I$, where $A\to A[T]$ is the natural inclusion and $A[T]\to B$ is $g$. This defines the sequence of maps $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \Bbb A^1_A \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ which agrees with our original map $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$.
Now we observe that for any ring $A$, the obvious projection $\Bbb A^1_A \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ factors as $\Bbb A^1_A \to \Bbb P^1_A \to \operatorname{Spec} A$, where the first map is the inclusion in to $D(x_1)$ and the second map is the obvious projection. To see this, write $\Bbb P^1_A$ as the gluing of $D(x_0)$ and $D(x_1)$, and note that the projection map is defined by the standard projection maps on each of these affine pieces.

This is delightfully well-written.
